# C++ constructor order

Tags: c++

How in this program while creating the object of the class C in main() , the default constructor AX and AXX is not calling in class C ,only parameter constructor is calling.How here default constructor is omitted here..even if we are creating the object of AX and AXX inside class C. As you can see in class B i don't have initialization list for AX object so the default constructor get called inside class B.
So here what is the fundamental we are using here o clear this concept ?
Can any one please help me in this for the below program ??

---

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
    A(){cout << "I am in the A constructor " << endl;}
    ~A(){cout << "I am In the A destructor "<< endl;}
};

class AX
{
    public:
    AX(){cout<<"I am in the AX constructor" << endl;}
    ~AX(){cout <<"I am in the AX destructor" << endl;}
    AX(int x){cout<<"I am in AX param constructor"<< endl;}

};
class AXX
{
    public:
    AXX(){cout << "I amin the AXX constructor"<<endl;}
    ~AXX(){cout << "I am in the AXX destructor "<< endl;}
    AXX(int x)
    {
        cout <<"I am in the AXX param constructor" << endl;
    }
};
 class B : public A
{
     AX ax;
     AXX axx;
    public:
     B():axx(6){cout <<"I amin B constructor"<< endl;}
     ~B(){cout << "I am in  the B destrcuctor "<< endl;}
 };
 class C : public B
 {
     AXX axx;
     AX ax;
     public : 
     C() : ax(5),axx(6) {cout << "I am in c constructor" << endl;}
          ~C(){cout << "I am in the c destructor" << endl;}
 };
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    C c1;
    return 0;
}
```

actual o/p:

- I am in the A constructor
- I am in the AX constructor
- I am in the AXX param constructor
- I amin B constructor
- I am in the AXX param constructor
- I am in AX param constructor
- I am in c constructor
- I am in the c destructor
- I am in the AX destructor
- I am in the AXX destructor
- I am in the B destrcuctor
- I am in the AXX destructor
- I am in the AX destructor
- I am In the A destructor

expected o/p :

- I am in the A constructor
- I am in the AX constructor
- I am in the AXX param constructor
- I amin B constructor
- I am in the AX constructor
- I am in the AXX constructor
- I am in the AXX param constructor
- I am in AX param constructor
- I am in c constructor
- I am in the c destructor
- I am in the AX destructor
- I am in the AXX destructor
- I am in the B destrcuctor
- I am in the AXX destructor
- I am in the AX destructor
- I am In the A destructor

Comment: Some more specific problem description would be immensely helpful.

Comment: I see all the constructors being called: http://ideone.com/nVTlUn

Comment: how here the parameter constructor is calling inside C class ,but before that i am creating the object of AX and AXX..so due to this default constructor should get called right ..but it is not calling and it is directly calling parameter constructor of AX and AXX....@cad

Comment: Initialisation lists are processed before the body of the constructor. This is a *good thing*.

Comment: what i am asking along with parameter constructor,default constructor should call in the class C section ...@Barmar

Comment: Because you changed the flow by specifying argument constructor for default C constructor as this:  C() : ax(5),axx(6). Changing to C() will call AX & AXX constructors.

Comment: @JitendraMahari Don't describe so much. Instead, post a copy of the output you're seeing and the output you're expecting.

Comment: actual o/p:
I am in the A constructor

I am in the AX constructor

I am in the AXX param constructor

I amin B constructor

I am in the AXX param constructor

I am in AX param constructor

I am in c constructor

I am in the c destructor

I am in the AX destructor

I am in the AXX destructor
I am in  the B destrcuctor

I am in the AXX destructor

I am in the AX destructor

I am In the A destructor

Comment: expected o/p :
I am in the A constructor

I am in the AX constructor

I am in the AXX param constructor

I amin B constructor

I am in the AX constructor

I am in the AXX constructor

I am in the AXX param constructor

I am in AX param constructor

I am in c constructor

I am in the c destructor

I am in the AX destructor

I am in the AXX destructor
I am in  the B destrcuctor

I am in the AXX destructor

I am in the AX destructor

I am In the A destructor

Comment: what i am telling if we have both default constructor and parameter constructor how the default constructor is omited ??

Comment: If you comment this code /* : ax(5),axx(6) */ , you will see this output as you want: A constructor 
AX constructor
AXX param constructor
B constructor
AXX constructor
AX constructor
C constructor
C destructor
AX destructor
AXX destructor 
B destrcuctor 
AXX destructor 
AX destructor
A destructor

Comment: @JitendraMahari please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34555771/edit) the post instead of adding these comments with the output

Answer (score 1):

Your expectation is wrong.  For each (sub) object only *one* constructor is called.  So for `c1.axx` it will be the parameterized constructor because the c constructor initializes it with a value.

Your expectation as to the order members are constructed in is also wrong.  `C.axx` is declared before `C.ax`, so it is constructed first.  The fact that `ax` appears first in the initializer list is irrelevant.  (Some compilers will warn about the order of declaration being different from the order in the initializer list.)

The reason for the order being the declaration order that the destruction order is the reverse of construction order.  If construction order was "initializer list order", what is the order of destruction for the following class?  (Note that the two constructors use a different order in the list).

```
class CC
 {
     AXX axx;
     AX ax;
     public : 
     CC() : ax(5),axx(6) {}
     CC(int a, int b) : axx(b), ax(a) {}
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

Each base class is fully constructed before the derived classes are constructed. After that, the order is defined by the field order in the class, each one with optional construction parameters through the constructor list. After that the body is executed.

To take your code, and expand and sort the construction lists, this is what you end up with:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
    A(){cout << "I am in the A constructor " << endl;}
    ~A(){cout << "I am In the A destructor "<< endl;}
};

class AX
{
    public:
    AX(){cout<<"I am in the AX constructor" << endl;}
    ~AX(){cout <<"I am in the AX destructor" << endl;}
    AX(int x){cout<<"I am in AX param constructor"<< endl;}

};
class AXX
{
    public:
    AXX(){cout << "I amin the AXX constructor"<<endl;}
    ~AXX(){cout << "I am in the AXX destructor "<< endl;}
    AXX(int x)
    {
        cout <<"I am in the AXX param constructor" << endl;
    }
};
 class B : public A
{
     AX ax;
     AXX axx;
    public:
     B() : A(), ax(), axx(6) {cout <<"I amin B constructor"<< endl;}
     ~B(){cout << "I am in  the B destrcuctor "<< endl;}
 };
 class C : public B
 {
     AXX axx;
     AX ax;
     public : 
     C() : B(), axx(6), ax(5) {cout << "I am in c constructor" << endl;}
     ~C(){cout << "I am in the c destructor" << endl;}
 };
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    C c1;
    return 0;
}
```

What's going on is the following:

- Constructor of C calls the constructor of B

  - Constructor of B calls the constructor of A

    - **Constructor of A calls its body**
  - Constructor of B calls the constructors on its fields in source-code order:

    - **Constructor of ax()**
    - **Constructor of axx(6)**
  - **Constructor of B calls its body**
- Constructor of C calls the constructors on its fields in source-code order:

  - **Constructor of axx(6)**
  - **Constructor of ax(5)**
- **Constructor of C calls its body**

Destruction is the reversed order.

In total, there are 4 fields in `C`. Namely `b::ax`, `b::axx`, `c::axx` and `c::ax`. In order, they're constructed with parameters `AX()`, `AXX(6)`, `AXX(6)`, `AX(5)`. Each field is properly constructed.

Without telling us what it is you're trying to achieve, or why you want that, I cannot further elaborate. The code is working as expected.

Comment: Inside the class C  we have AXX axx; AX ax; before the C constructor.So why it is not calling these default constructor before the parameter constructor. @Aidiakapi

Comment: @JitendraMahari Because as I mentioned, the construction order is fixed, regardless of what you type in your source code. It first constructs the base class, then all the fields in the order in which they are defined in the class body. **Not the order in which they are defined in the constructor list.**

Comment: @JitendraMahari That's also why it is considered a bug, or a code-smell when your constructor lists' order differentiates from the field order. Tools like Resharper C++ will tell you to sort the constructor list to match the field layout.

Comment: You mean to say in the class if we defined or initialized the constructor parameter constructor will get call(initialization list),even though we have already created a object for that class. Am i correct ??@Aidiakapi

Comment: @JitendraMahari No, what I say is that if you have `class N : public M { type fX, fY; N(type fy, type fx) : fY(fy), fX(fx), M(fx, fy) { };` that it's going to execute in the order `: M(fx, fy), fX(fx), fY(fy)`. Because it first constructs the base class, then the fields in the order in which they are defined in the class body. The constructor list's (I prefer that over the term initializer list, due to C++11s initializer lists) order doesn't matter at all. The order is regardless of what you type in the initializer list.